# Implement a Community Wiki Sandbox (long work-in-progress drafts can cause issues)

Tags: discussion

Suggest we implement a community wiki sandbox to minimize issues related to long work-in-progress drafts. Here's an example from meta.math.se:

- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers

Excerpt from above:

- This sandbox is intended for saving drafts of long, complex answers, especially answers whose composition takes a long time. It serves to localize to one thread the front-page "bumps" caused by edits to drafts of such answers, so that they may be easily ignored. Also, it helps to guard against losing longly-composed answers due to system crashes.  When you are happy with your draft here, you may simply copy the code and paste it to the desired location.

---

Related links for reference.

- [Where is " Wiki " ? ( was Wiki wonky, Taggy waggy - Menu venue? )](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/where-is-wiki-was-wiki-wonky-taggy-waggy-menu-venue)
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/